# Как при наведении(hover) сделать так, чтобы появлялась иконка над словом?

Tags: css

Вот наводишь мышку а над словом появляется иконка маленькая , любая...как сделать?

Comment: Ты всё ещё слаб, Саске..))

Comment: Возможно , но я всё же вернулся :D

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант, можно подключить иконочный шрифт (или использовать emoji), код которого записать в data-атрибут. А потом его значение передать в css. Что-то вроде такого:

```css
p:hover:before {
  content: attr(data-icon);
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<p data-icon="">слово</p>
```

Comment: спасибо большое очень помогли. кстати вопрос , а вы может знаете как сделать блок на весь экран  с бустрапом?  есть блок 400пх ширина и при маленьком экране он в левой стороне и col-12 col-sm-12 показывается что он должен быть на весь экран , но он из за ширины 400 всё равно слева. как сделать чтоб он был на полный экран, когда экран становится меньше?